# Truthness of the following inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Which of the following inequality(/s) is(/are) NOT true for $x\in \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)$.
>
> (A) $\displaystyle e^{-x}>\sum_{j=0}^2\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}$
>
> (B) $\displaystyle e^{-x}<\sum_{j=0}^3\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}$
>
> (C) $\displaystyle e^{-x}>\sum_{j=0}^4\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}$
>
> (D)$\displaystyle e^{-x}>\sum_{j=0}^5\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}$

We have , $\displaystyle e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots>1+x$. Then , $\displaystyle e^{-x}<(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots \approx 1-x+x^2$.

But it doesn't help me. How we can deduce these inequalities ?

**Update :**

From 'Nathaniel Mayer's answer I got it. As $\displaystyle |s_n-s|<a_n$ , where $s_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum of the series and $s$ is the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$ , so only inequality given in the option (D) is correct. **But I can't realize where the given interval works ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor series for $e^{-x}$ is an alternating sum. For an alternating sum, the absolute value of the n-th term is greater than the absolute value of the sum of all the later terms. (See e.g. https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8w10/public_html/m8l09.pdf) It follows that if I take the partial sum $s_n$ of the first n terms, and the n-th term is positive (respectively negative), then $s_n$ is an upper (resp. lower) bound for the series.

In fact your problem is incorrect, only one of those answers is true.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by ' problem is incorrect ' . Only one answer is true ? which one ?

Comment: The problem says "which of these is NOT true". In fact only one is true. It's D.

Comment: @@Nathaniel Mayer) Well...I got is..But one question..where the interval is needed ?

Comment: The sum is only alternating for $x > 0$, it's important that the interval is on the positive real axis. Beyond that, it doesn't matter. Just the way they decided to write the problem I guess.